# In AOSP 4.2.2 what private APIs in NotificationManager can be used to list all system notifications?

Tags: android-source

If I am compiling AOSP 4.2.2 from source, what private APIs in NotificationManager can I use to display system notifications?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below api.

```
 private INotificationManager mNoMan;

 mNoMan = INotificationManager.Stub.asInterface(
              ServiceManager.getService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE));


StatusBarNotification[] notis = mNoMan.getActiveNotifications(mContext.getPackageName());
```

You need this permission

```
android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATIONS
```

Comment: IRRC `ACCESS_NOTIFICATIONS` is signature or system, so beware that I won't simply work if you add it to your Manifest.

Comment: @flow so how do you do it?